# UILabel Transperent Text to see thru its subviews

Tags: image, label, mask, nsattributedstring

I want to have a functionality of transparent text in `UILabel` I have seen one sample called named `RSMaskedLabel`. For label I am using `OHAttributed` label to use some extended functionality. So I merged some code of `RSMaskedLabel` to `OHAttributed` label's `drawTextInRect` method. Now I can see background image from label text. But what if I want to change that text color, set alpha of that masked text? I am giving some screenshot of [FontCandy](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/font-candy-%2b/id691025552?mt=8&ei=iY5_UqqRMImNrQeN9YHADA&usg=AFQjCNFIZ0QgoiTj1KEdU7Isj5M5FkdzYQ) app. I want exact functionality like that app to write text on the image. I tried a lot since last 70 hours but no luck till now. if someone wants then I can upload my demo what I have done till now. please help..[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add another UILabel with same frame of your label and and add your your label over that label set super view label background as clear set text colour as you want with alpha value.
with the font slider change alpha value of colour of super view label